# How can I pass value of the variables gained during runtime to the Update query using sqlite3 in C?

Tags: c, sqlite

Here is the code, I just want to pass the value of the variable `new_pin` to the database and update the particular row of  column called `pin_number` in my database table called `user_data`

```
void change_pin_number( struct user a) {
    int new_pin,check_pin;
    printf("\nPlease enter your previous pin number: ");
    scanf("%d", &check_pin);
    if(check_pin== a.pin_number)
    {
        printf("\n\nPlease enter your new pin number: ");
        scanf("%d", &new_pin);

        char *query = sqlite3_mprintf(" UPDATE user_data SET pin_number=new_pin WHERE id= 1");
```

Comment: You probably want this: `char *query = sqlite3_mprintf("UPDATE user_data SET pin_number=%d WHERE id= 1", new_pin);`. Read [this](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/mprintf.html) for more information

Comment: You could also bind the number to a parameter in a prepared statement using `sqlite3_bind_int()`.